# Currently take CS50, having trouble understanding why this works?

Tags: c, function, loops, operators, cs50

```
int i;
do
{
    i = get_int("height: ");
}
while (i < 1);

for(int n = 0; n < i; n++)
{
    printf("#");    
}
printf("\n");
```

This code executes in the terminal properly but I don't understand how this part
`for(int n = 0; n < i; n++)` allows for the user to input a positive integer and it prints the correct amount.

The way I am thinking out it is that the top part gets the users integer and assigns it to `i`, and it will has until a positive integer is given.
But I don't get how the loop works.

Why does assigning 0 to `n` and having `n` be less than `i` and incrementing `n` by 1 using `n++` give the result of printing the hashes `"#"` according to the users input?

If anyone could please help me understand it would be greatly appreciated, new to code and C.

Comment: This might help - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of a `for` loop in C:

```
for ( expr1opt ; expr2opt ; expr3opt )
  statement

for ( declaration expr2opt ; expr3opt )
  statement
```

First, if it’s present, either *`expr1`* or the *`declaration`* is evaluated - this expression usually initializes our loop counter or otherwise sets up the thing *`expr2`* tests against.  In this case, we’re declaring the counter `n` and initializing it to 0.

Next, if it’s present, *`expr2`* is evaluated (if it’s not present, a non-zero value is assumed).  If the result of the expression is a non-zero value, the loop body is executed.  In this case, the loop body is executed if the value of `n` is less than `i`.

Finally, *`expr3`* is evaluated.  This expression usually updates the loop counter or whatever thing *`expr2`* tests against.  In this case, it’s incrementing `n` by 1.

So the way this particular loop works is:

1. Declare and initialize `n` to 0 (*`declaration`*)
2. If `n` is less than `i` then go to 3, else go to 6 (*`expr2`*)
3. Print a hash character (*`statement`*)
4. Add 1 to `n` (*`expr3`*)
5. Go to 2
6. End loop

**Edit**

For people asking about the missing semicolon in the second form, a *`declaration`* includes a terminating `;`:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
```

Comment: Should "for ( declaration expr2opt ; expr3opt )" include 2 ";" and not just one?  C17dr 6.8.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes CS50. So basically how this line => `for(int n = 0; n < i; n++)`
checks if the number is positive or not is first lets subsitite 0 to n. So it would be basically => `for(int n = 0; 0< i; n++)`. so that means that `i` has to be greater than 0. If not the for loop WON'T execute. so if the `i` value is 5. 0<5 is true so that means that for loop WILL execute.. if the `i` value is -1. 0<-1 is false so the for loop WON'T execute. if u entered 5 it will repeat 5 times.(if the `i` value is 5) because you are starting for 0 then incrementing(n++) 5 times.